# PostgreSQL did not released space "UPDATE set column = null", vacuum did not worked too

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

I have a huge table that I cannot delete the rows, only update the columns that are storing huge base64 data, that I should update to null to try to release space.

So I programmed a script that are able to set all the images in base64 expecting that the space will be released after Vacuum!

The **images are set to null**, **vacuum** executed, but the table is still with the exactly same size, and I am pretty sure the space must be released immediately, so what I am doing wrong?

Will **vacuum full** able to release space from huge varchar data that I updated to null? (Because I will need to lock the table if I will do this and I need to be sure)

The dump size decreased by 10 times so I expect similar behavior on the database size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - Yes.

When you update rows, you create a new version of each row that is held *inside* the table.

- **Vacuum** does not *remove* these row versions.
  It *does* make the space occupied by these "dead" rows available for reuse, but that *doesn't* reduce the overall size.
- **Vacuum Full** removes the dead rows completely.
  That's what releases space back to the operating system.
  And yes; the table will get locked up while this is happening.

See the [PostgreSQL Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/VACUUM_FULL) page on "Vacuum Full".

Comment: Log of vacuum full.... 
ERROR:  could not extend file "base/63212/4702406.54": No space left on device 
D :-(

Comment: VACUUM FULL basically writes a new copy of the table without all the "dead" stuff.  
That needs space.

Comment: Phill W that helped a lot because I know now the exact space that I would need to release to run vacuum full; Thank you for your help! It would be wonderful if it was possible to work in a different tablespace with vacuum full....